# How to insert external stylesheet in JavaScript (dynamically)

Tags: javascript

...with right path.

For example. I have script called foo.js. I'd like to insert stylesheet declaration which I can do with following instruction:

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/template/foo.css" type="text/css" />');
```

**Problem**: I have to put full path to the stylesheet file. So instead of /template/foo.css I have to put: http://hostname/directory/template/foo.css. I can't set it statically beacause script can be placed in different servers and different locations. So it can be: http://foo.com/bar/foo.css or http://foo.com/foo.css.

It would be very useful if I can get path of foo.js file on the server. That would be good enough beacause then I could set stylesheet location based on the javascrpt's file.

Comment: I have noticed that TinyMCE does that

Comment: Is there a definite relationship between the locations of foo.js and foo.css, such as the same directory?  Or perhaps between the html page and the css file?

Comment: is there some kind of logic of where to find the css file ?

Comment: Yes. Let's just say that foo.js and foo.css are in the same directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've always done:

```
$('body').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/template/foo.css" type="text/css" />');
```

instead of **head**

Ahh... sorry I just realised what your problem is. One strategy is to extract the path of the script from the DOM itself:

```
$('script').each(function(i,el){
    var path = el.src.match(/^(.+)\/foo.js$/);
    if (path) {
        $('body').append('<link rel="stylesheet" ' +
                                'href="' + path[1] + '/foo.css" ' +
                                'type="text/css" />'
                        );
    }
})
```

Comment: You could use `$('script[src]')` to iterate only the `script` elements that have a `src` attribute...

Comment: Thank you. I thought there is another way to do that. But apparently not :) Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a common technique that I use to get the current script url:

```
var scriptUrl = (function() {
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
      script = scripts[scripts.length - 1];

  return script.src;
})();
```

It works basically because when the script is being executed, it is the last `script` tag on the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location` and obtain the path from that. For example for this page it is:

```
>>> window.location
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033742/how-to-insert-external-stylesheet-in-javascript-dynamically
```

Comment: In this way you are obtaining the location object for the page where the css is included, not the css file location.