# CSS file sometimes load and sometimes not

Tags: javascript, css

I am calling a css file in the js function but it sometimes load and some times not. Like after 2 3 tries it will load. Help would be appreciated.

**js:**

```
<script>
function PrintContent()
{

        w=window.open();
        w.document.write($('#'+Get_Current_Report_id).html());
        w.document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../../Extra/Reports Pages/Print.css'>");
        w.print();
        w.close();
    }
}
</script>
```

I also used `writeln` but that also didn't help.

**edit:**

Use this. Till now getting every things right.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#PrintContent').click(function()
    {
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not just include it in the parent window and set it to media=print, that way you don't have to open a new window, which makes no sense at all ?

Comment: Some advice I was taught: "If you're using `document.write`, you're probably wrong."

Comment: w.document.write($('#'+Get_Current_Report_id)+'.html)');

Comment: @adeneo i already tried that it didn't help either. i am calling this css file for print.

Comment: I get that, and stylesheets have a media attribute that you can set to print, that way the stylesheet only works on printed content.

Comment: what should i use now @RUJordan

Comment: @adeneo i also tried setting media="print" but i thats not helping me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert external stylesheet in javascript dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033742/how-to-insert-external-stylesheet-in-javascript-dynamically).

Comment: One thing I would try and avoid is using paths containing spaces for web applications.  Another thing is URL:s like "../../xyz".  I don't know if either are the root of your problem here, but I  would try and avoid both.  As said by others, do not add the css with javascript at all, but simply put it in the head of the main page with a media="print" attribute

Comment: okay thanks for the tips guys. I will remember. Will again try using css in the head part.

Comment: @user3400389 use the document object model!

Comment: i updated above. that's working pretty fine.